# Manchester Airport connection with 1:15 transfer time

Tags: short-connections, man

I am flying from Boston to Amsterdam via Manchester where I have only 75 minutes between the two flights. I need to change terminals and I guess I need to pass Security since I am flying from outside the EU.

Will this be enough time?

Comment: Your guess about security (I presume you mean immigration) is not correct, as the UK is **not** a part of the Schengen area. However, I'm not sure if it is possible to transit airside between terminals at Manchester. Are both flights on the same ticket, and will baggage be checked through?

Comment: See: http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/at-the-airport/airport-transfers/ - it is possible to stay airside, which is good. It's still a pretty tight change, but if its same ticket, that's the airlines problem more than yours. ALthough it's really, really weird to end up changing at Manchester to go to Europe's biggest hub.

Comment: Oh, yes you are of course totally right about the UK not being part of Schengen!baggage should be checked through.

Comment: The airline said that if they touch down on time, they are not responsible any mort. It is thus my problem whether I catch the flight or not... :-(

Comment: The airport site is not quite clear to me: They have a heading "transfer process for airlines that do not offer a transfer facility" and then they say that transfer from T3 to T1 is 5 minutes, but later on for "ransfer process for airlines offering a transfer facility", which I guess my flight would be, they say that one has to go to the Transfer Center and go through security for international to international connections. So apparently I do need to go through security.

Comment: @kkk Well they were wrong. If you walk straight to the next gate and still dont make it, it is **entirely** the airline's problem

Comment: Depends on how you see it: If they just do not issue a new ticket, it IS my problem...

Comment: @CMaster It is NOT possible to transfer airside between any terminal at Manchester. This is because T1/T3 and T2 are physically different buildings about half a mile apart, and T1 and T3 do not have an internal walkway.

Comment: Ok, now I am seriously confused. On their website they explicitly say that there is an (exteranal not internal - whatever that means) walkway which takes 5 minutes. Why on earth do they not simply give minimum connection times as any other normal airport, instead of writing long texts that do not help anyone???

Comment: As you're coming from a non-UK airport, you'll have to re-clear security at the very least. Recent comments on FlyerTalk [in this thread](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/u-k-ireland/1811924-security-lhr-t5-always-bad-i-just-unlucky.html) (talking about LHR but it went off topic) suggests queues and staff attitudes aren't great, so I wouldn't have that much hope in making it...

Comment: I have searched that thread, but I could not find the word "Manchester" anywhere - it does seem to be LHR specific...

Comment: @VirtualAnomalythe Manchester website seem to mention an "airside" bus. I'm aware they are separate buildings. You will need to reclear security (bag scans etc) but should be able to avoid immigration.

Answer (score 2):

If you're booked on a single ticket, and it wouldn't be awful if you ended up being a few hours late in Amsterdam, then I wouldn't worry. There are lots of flights from Manchester to Amsterdam (around 10-15 direct per day), and you'll just be put on a later one.

In terms of the transfer experience, here's one person's experience of a 1h15m international to domestic airside connection at Manchester - it took 40 minutes from arrival to being at the gate for the next flight. It also seems to be a worst-case in terms of time spent waiting for the bus and includes a passport check you wouldn't have to go through: http://philatravelgirl.com/connecting_in_manchester_phl-man_airport_/

The link also implies that you get a separate security area so as long as you're quick off the bus to the connections centre you shouldn't have to wait for too long.